# Replace all identical files, ask for all non-identical

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

How can I replace all identical files when moving files to different folders, but summon a dialog when there are non identical files with the same name? I am using nautilus. If there is no way, I am willing to switch file managers.

Comment: If identical, why bother replacing?

Comment: @user535733 Maybe the filenames are identical in the source and the destination, but some of the files in the destination got corrupt, so that OP wants to replace them (I encountered the exact same situation today, and found out the corrupt files by comparing size of directories using (manual) binary search).

Comment: @IssacW Can you please explain your issue in greater detail?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Use `fdupes`.

Comment: @user535733 Replacing would be equivalent to deleting the original.

Comment: no gui but look into fdupes

https://vitux.com/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files-in-ubuntu-using-fdupes/